# Sourcing unstored field to stored field in NetSuite via workflow - not working

Tags: netsuite

I created a PO approval workflow which includes storing the rejection reasons in a custom record.

The process is the user rejects the PO, gets redirected to the custom record to enter the reason, then saves. This works.

I then created an unstored field on the PO that pulls the rejection reason via a saved search. This works too.

However, when I try to pull the unstored field value to a stored field value (both fields are on the PO) via the same workflow, nothing happens. I tried different triggers (entry, before record submit, before user submit, and after record submit). The goal is to include this reason in the email sent to the PO creator (why the PO was rejected).

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? Thanks all.

I tried different workflow triggers. I also checked NetSuite's SuiteAnswers and have seen answer IDs about how that workflow (set field value from unstored to stored fields) should be set up.

Unstored field setup:

[Unstored field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyVmp.png)

[Unstored field source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi3aW.png)

Stored field setup:

[Stored field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3d3t.png)

Workflow action:

[Set field value workflow action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE6Cp.png)

Comment: The only way someone can know what you are doing wrong is if you post the code you tried.

Comment: Hi! No scripts are involved but I can share a screenshot of the workflow action/state. Thanks!

Comment: Hope thats enough for someone to help you.